# Does anyone have a valid and working example of OpenLDAP meta backend?

Tags: openldap

I have been Google'ing my fingers off and simply can not find a working example of how to merge/proxy a OpenLDAP server and windows AD server. Have anyone worked with this before?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The idea is simple:

openldap.mydomain.local   ----> Linux LDAP Server

winad.mydomain.local      ----> Windows AD Server

Some users are one Linux and some on WinAD. OpenLDAP should search both on login.
A working example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find an example here:
[http://blog.sejo.be/2010/01/8/openldap-en-3-ad-servers/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130130094844/http://blog.sejo.be/2010/01/8/openldap-en-3-ad-servers/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and follow the discussions.

http://blog.scottlowe.org/2007/01/15/linux-ad-integration-version-4/

Maybe you could try samba4, that should give much more integration with AD.
It's still in alpha stage, but you could try it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following github project:

https://github.com/kgalal/meta-ldap

This sets up a meta-ldap server that proxies OpenLDAP and WindowsAD, and presents the result in a single output